# Does Swift Package Manager have a local cache?

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

Every time I load a new package, Xcode redownloads all dependencies from Github, instead of reusing some that I've already loaded for other projects.

For instance I would expect that when I reference `.package(name: "SwiftyJSON", url: "https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git", from: "5.0.0")` and when I have a matching package on my laptop, Xcode would not redownload the package.

Is it possible to configure Xcode to use a more aggressive caching strategy?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From Xcode 12.5 the dependencies are cached in `~/Library/Caches/org.swift.swiftpm/`

**EDIT**

Not the compiled dependencies but only the source (checkouts) are cached in this place. It seems we have to wait for yet another update until Apple offers a `xcodebuild` option to pass the `build_path` for the dependencies.

Comment: This is great news!

Comment: What about `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and `.build/SourcePackages`? What's the relationship between them?

Comment: Close XCode. `rm -rfv ~/Library/Caches/org.swift.swiftpm/` and `rm -rfv ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and `rm -rfv <Project Path>/DerivedData`  Then open XCode is what worked